# How to center a text in javascript inside jade template?

Tags: javascript, pug

[image]I have retrieve from a query a variable with this content:

```
geneModel = [
    {
        x: 35,
        y: 55, 
        description: "CC", 
        id: "CC"
    },
    {
        x: 122, 
        y: 142, 
        description: "CC", 
        id: "CC"
    },
    {
        x: 3, 
        y: 14, 
        description: "TIR", 
        id: "TIR"
    }
]
```

I would like to center description field in the output, but I don't know how to do that inside a javascript code which is inside a template jade.

I have attached the code below:

```
 body(role='document')

  .row.jumbotron
    h3
      strong Gene model
         #div1.col-md-10.col-md-offset-1(style='margin-top: 0px')
      script.
         var FeatureViewer = require("feature-viewer");
         //Create a new Feature Viewer and add some rendering options
         window.onload = function() {
         //Create a new Feature Viewer and add some rendering options
         var ft2 = new FeatureViewer("...", {
         showAxis: true,
         showSequence: true,
         brushActive: true,
         toolbar:true,
         bubbleHelp:true,
         zoomMax:10
         });
         //Add some features        
         ft2.addFeature({
         data: "#{geneModel}",
         name: "Domains",
         className: "test4",
         color: "#F4D4AD",
         type: "rect",
         height: 30,
         filter: "type1",
         style: "align-center"
         });
         };
```

Comment: You don't need javascript for that, you are adding a class name test4, add css  'text-align: centre' to that class.

Comment: I tried what you said before, and it does not work...

Comment: Can you add the output of your jade file here as well? The relevant portion

Comment: I have just updated

Comment: I was talking about the html output, so I could see the classes/ids etc if any applied

Comment: The template is written in jade + bootstrap, and the script is directly inside the body of the jade, .row.jumbotron draws a green box and inside this box the script is execute and make the model (TIR, CC, CC).

Comment: Can you copy the rendered html for me, I cannot help otherwise. Use a developer tool, copy as html should do the trick